# jquery file upload file upload using input type hidden request

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am using jquery file upload

https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

I have 2 forms and i want to upload file based on request.It uploads on specific folder properly but when i refresh it does not show it in grid.

Here is my index file code for file upload

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');


$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($_REQUEST['move']);
```

I passed this in constructor of uploadfile.php and modified code like this

```
 function __construct($move,$options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {

            $this->response = array();
            $this->options = array(
                'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
                'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/'.$move.'/',
                'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$move.'/',
```

And Here are the Html where i am processing form

```
 <form name="customupload" action="" method="post">

     <input type="hidden" value="files" name="foldername">

     <input type="submit" value="Background">

 </form>    

 <form name="customupload_new" action="" method="post">

     <input type="hidden" value="bc" name="foldername">

     <input type="submit" value="Frame">

 </form>
```

And here in filepload js function i pass extra data as move parameter

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: 'http://localhost/projectname/fileupload/',
          formData: {move: '<?php if(isset($_REQUEST["foldername"])) echo $_REQUEST["foldername"];?>'   }

    });
```

All issue Happen because this index file is loaded via ajax and here it does not
read value when page loads it reads the extra parameter when file is uploaded.

If i put static value it shows in grid for eg.

```
'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/myfolder',
        'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/myfolder',
```